# How can I view Office files in Windows Phone app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, ms-office

I want to develop an Windows Phone 8.1 app which can view office files without launch the other apps.

But I can not find any free SDK or framework or component to do that.

So, doesn't Microsoft provide any way to developer just viewing Office document in Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard tools for viewing Office documents in your application. You can only open the file in Office.

But you can use alternative library.

For example

[C1Excel library](http://our.componentone.com/2014/01/03/load-and-display-excel-files-in-your-windows-phone-app/) or

[Essential Studio for Windows Phone](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone)

Comment: Is there any library that is able to open and view powerpoint (.ppt) file?